# nodejs app deployment using gcloud errors out

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy my nodejs API app for sometime to google cloud platform. Unfortunately it errors out saying this:
[image]

I do have the app.yaml file set with these commands

```
runtime: nodejs  
env: flex
```

And this is the start file that I am trying to deploy

```
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : '35.230.**.**',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '*********',
    database : 'sale*******er'
});
//Connect
db.connect((err) => {
    if(err){throw err;}
    // console.log('Connected to Sales Tracker database!');
})
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080
app.use('/backend', backend);
app.listen(port, () => {
    // console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: You're conditioning your app starting correctly on the success of the SQL server connection. A connection failure will cause problems during deployment which measures the deployment success based on the app starting correctly. IMHO a better approach would be to manage such connection in the background, after your app starts.

Comment: Hello @DanCornilescu. I do have the mySQL database on the Google cloud SQL as well. This nodejs app I am trying to deploy has the endpoints to connect to database on cloud SQL. As you mentoned how do I manage the connection in the background.

Comment: Not quite sure, I'm not using SQL. In the standard environment I'd enqueue a push queue task to take care of it, but that's just in alpha support on flex. Maybe use the first external request as trigger?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer from another post
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'ip_address',
        user     : 'root',
        password : 'password',
        database : 'database_name'
        socketPath: “/cloudsql/projectName:zone:instance-name”
    });
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49169561/3826733